# Convert .indd documents to PDF using .net application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, pdf-generation

I've developed a .net application to convert multiple InDesign documents to pdf......
Here raised an error while converting indd documents to pdf...
My error is 
**error CS0103:** The name 'idExportFormat' does not exist in the current context
**error CS0103:** The name 'objInDesign' does not exist in the current context
**error CS1061:** 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Export' and no extension method 'Export' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Code i have used is

```
if (rb_indesigndoc.Checked == true)
{
MessageBox.Show("InDesign document","Toolkit");
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourcefolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, "*.indd");
if (fileEntries.Length > 0)
{
MessageBox.Show("indesign douments found", "Doument found toolkit");
foreach (string file in fileEntries)
{
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
string[] docname = filename.Split('.');
string doc = docname[0];
string cstrOutputFile = txt_destinationpath.Text.ToString() + "\\" + doc + ".pdf";
doc.Export(idExportFormat.idPDFType, cstrOutputFile, false, objInDesign.PDFExportPresets["[High Quality Print]"]);
}
}
}
```

But while including this line to export the above error occurs....
The line is

```
doc.Export(idExportFormat.idPDFType, cstrOutputFile, false, objInDesign.PDFExportPresets["[High Quality Print]"]);
```

what i want to do??????????????

Comment: Where are `idExportFormat` and `objInDesign` defined? The shown codes does show this. Also, `doc` is a `string`, and therefore does not have an `Export` method. It seems that you are trying to use some library. Are you following some tutorial or something?

Comment: Yeah! your right..... Now i'm trying to avoid those library, by avoiding that how can i generate into pdf??????